# locationManager:didUpdateLocations being called non stop when allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am setting the following, which I would assume would NOT call "didUpdateLocations" according to my parameters, but its calling it about 3 times a second?

```
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager setActivityType:CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation];
    [self.locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:15 timeout:3000.0];
```

After setting "allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled" it is still calling it about 3 times a second?

Comment: Another note that might be relevant is that `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:` only applies while the app is in the background. The docs say that the app will receive updates normally while the app is in the foreground. They also say that if another app is using GPS (such as maps) then your app may still get updates normally even while in the background.

Comment: Note that deferring location won't work when you run the app with the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve part of your desired outcome - only update if they travel further than 15m - with

```
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 15;
```

From the docs: "The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated."

Have just used in my iOS7/8 app and seems to work fine in foreground.

For the time between triggering, suggest you use CLLocation timestamp.

Comment: allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout: fails instantly if there is a distance filter of more than 0

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/CLLocationDistanceMax,  In addition, the distanceFilter property of the location manager must be set to kCLDistanceFilterNone. If it is set to any other value, the location manager reports a kCLErrorDeferredDistanceFiltered error.

Answer (score 0):

when you setActivityType to CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation your telling your app that your a navigation app so will likely be very active.  Using the navigation setting will cause your app to use more than just the gps hardware (for example accelerometer).  The doc basically says this will drain your battery in an instant and you should plan to have the device plugged in while active.

Also allowDeferredLocationUpdates is for use when your app is backgrounded.  It says you care about receiving the location updates but you don't need them in real time so don't wake the app up all the time.

If you want to pause because your not moving try setting pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically.

Comment: I set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to YES, which is the default and commented out the setActivityType: call and it still updates about 3 times a second.

Comment: While your app is in the foreground you don't have any fine grained control of how often you receive updates.  You can use the distance filter to only generate events when you move a certain distance which can help.  The other thing you can do is to lower the desired accuracy.  Setting the correct activity type can also help the system determine when to delay or not deliver events.  If you want constant updates that as fine grained as you'll get.

Comment: I want to only update if they travel further than 15 meters and at max only every 3 seconds, which to me is what allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled: is suppose to do. It doesn't do either of these. As far as accuracy goes, that isn't true. I want to be as accurate as possible, so I know exactly where they are at, but just don't update as often.

Comment: It does do that, but it only works while your app is in the background.  The doc is very clear on the behavior.  There is a timestamp on the location updates so if you need the 15 meters and 3 second max you could implement your own filter which ignores the ones you don't want.  You should be able to get the 15 meter requirement filled by using the distance filter.